# Unable to run flutter project

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, sdk

I've installed flutter SDK and started a new sample project , but couldn't run it ,here is the logCat

[image]

I tried running it on both android studio and VsCode and got the exact same log message.

When I tied running `flutter doctor` command in terminal I got this error:-

[image]

I think the issue is in the Dart-SDK but I've downloaded it from the flutter page as well as from Dart documentation.

Here are my environment variables in **path**

> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe;C:\Windows\System32;C:\flutter\flutter\bin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting flutter in **C:\src** (full path should be : C:\src\flutter\ )

You should also update your env variables in path to : **C:\src\flutter\bin**, do that also for Dart sdk, env variable should be : **C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin**

After That go to command line and type `flutter doctor`.